# res.clearCookie working locally but not once deployed to production

Tags: reactjs, express, apollo-server

I am using my apollo-server to handle the issue and clearing of cookies when a user logs in or logs out. Locally the cookies get cleared like they they should but once we deployed the app to our production server, the cookies remain with no errors or warning.

sendCookies is called after a successful login
clearCookies is called after a successful logout

UPDATE: it looks like its due to the `.` being appended to the start of the domain that is causing the issue. Any ideas on why its appending the `.` even though its setting the domain to apps.dbiservices.com. I tried hardcoding it and it resulted in the same results. I know there are articles stating that it ignores the `.` but it's what preventing my cookies from being removed. If I edit the domain and remove the . and logout it works

Here are my functions that handle the construction of the cookie options

```
// used to expire when day rolls over
const midnightExpiration = (date) => {
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 1, 0, 0, 0);
};

// extract the domain from the req.origin.header
const extractDomain = (url) => {
    return new URL(url)?.hostname;
};

// used to create our cookie
const cookieCreationOptions = (host) => {
    return {
        expires: midnightExpiration(new Date()),
        domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? COOKIE_DOMAIN : extractDomain(host),
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
        sameSite: 'Strict'
    }
}

// used to set the expiration options for our cookies
const cookieExpirationOptions = (host) => {
    return {
        expires: new Date(0),
        domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? COOKIE_DOMAIN : extractDomain(host),
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false,
        sameSite: 'Strict'
    }
}

// sends our cookies
const sendCookies = (req, res, newTokens) => {
    if (stringToBoolean(USE_COOKIES)) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);

        res.cookie('x-access-token', newTokens.accessToken, cookieCreationOptions(req.headers.origin));
        res.cookie('x-refresh-token', newTokens.refreshToken, cookieCreationOptions(req.headers.origin));   
    }
};

// clears out our cookies
const clearCookies = (_req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie('x-access-token', cookieExpirationOptions);
    res.clearCookie('x-refresh-token', cookieExpirationOptions);
};
```

As said it works as it should  when running both client / server locally. You can see in the Response Headers cookies are being set any ideas on how to get correct this to work

[image: Login response]
[image: Cookies]
[image: Response Cookies]
[image: Response Headers]

Comment: the cookie which is stuck, has a leading `.`, also what is the value of COOKIE_DOMAIN? as its taking precedence over req.headers.origin if on production. btw req.headers.origin can be user set.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the `COOKIE_DOMAIN=apps.dbiservices.com`. I have also tried hard coding it to the same `apps.dbiservices.com` yet it still adds the leading `.`